How to Track Conversions on Cart and Checkout Pages with Google Tag Manager on Shopify?
I'm currently working on a Shopify-based e-commerce site and using Google Tag Manager (GTM) to track conversions. I've successfully set up conversion tracking on product detail pages, but I'm having trouble tracking conversions on the cart and checkout pages.
It seems like the conversions are not being recorded on these specific pages. Are there any special settings or steps I need to follow to ensure that GTM can track conversions on the cart and checkout pages?
Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
What did you try?
I've added GTM tags and triggers to the cart and checkout pages.
Ensured that the GTM container is properly installed and published.
Verified that the tags are firing on the cart and checkout pages using GTM's Preview and Debug mode.
What were you expecting?
I expected GTM to track conversions on the cart and checkout pages, similar to how it tracks conversions on the product detail pages.
Conversion events to be recorded in Google Analytics (or other linked services) when users add items to the cart or complete a purchase.
Despite these efforts, the conversions on these specific pages are not being recorded. Are there any special settings or steps I need to follow to ensure that GTM can track conversions on the cart and checkout pages?
Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
